# Is there a better way to calculate age of content

Tags: javascript, date-arithmetic

I have written a code to calculate the age of content on a website. It's inefficient, and the calculations are way off. I've written this script before, and last time it worked perfectly, but I can't find the damn file it's in.

I think the calculation problem is caused by the year. Can anyone suggest a fix up for me? Created date format is YYYYMMDD and output is in whole weeks (this is important), i.e. the example below should output '52' weeks.

```
var created='20120223';
var year=Number(created.substr(0,4));
var month=Number(created.substr(4,2))-1;
var day=Number(created.substr(6,2));
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var input_age = ((((curr_year - year)*31536000) + ((curr_month - month)*2678400) + ((curr_date - day)*86400))/604800).toFixed(0);
document.getElementById('item12345_input').value = input_age + ' weeks';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are subtracting a month first. then you are again adding a month. try this

```
    var created='20120223';
var year=Number(created.substr(0,4));
var month=Number(created.substr(4,2))-1;
var day=Number(created.substr(6,2));
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var input_age = ((((curr_year - year)*31536000) + ((curr_month - month)*2678400) + ((curr_date - day)*86400))/604800).toFixed(0);
alert(input_age + ' weeks');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the 2 dates.

```
var createdDate = new Date(
    +created.substring(0, 4),  // Four digit year
    created.substring(4, 6)-1, // Base-zero month
    +created.substring(6, 8)); // Day of month
var ageMillis = (new Date) - createdDate;
var MS_PER_WEEK = 1000/* ms /sec */
                * 60  /* sec/min */
                * 60  /* min/hr  */
                * 24  /* hr /day */
                * 7   /* day/wk  */;
var ageWeeks = ageMillis / MS_PER_WEEK;
```

Comment: Ahem - months are 0 based.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this looks efficient and precise. One question, are you able to modify slightly to include the value for created date (i.e. 20120130)?

Answer (score 0):

Note Months are 0 based

```
<script>
var created ="20120223";
var yyyy  = +created.substring(0, 4);
var mm    = created.substring(4, 6)-1;
var dd    = +created.substring(6, 8);
var createdDate = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);
var ageMillis = new Date().getTime() - createdDate.getTime();
var MS_PER_WEEK = 1000/* ms /sec */
                * 60  /* sec/min */
                * 60  /* min/hr  */
                * 24  /* hr /day */
                * 7   /* day/wk  */;
var ageWeeks = parseInt(ageMillis / MS_PER_WEEK);

alert("Created on " +mm+"/"+dd+"/"+yyyy+" which is "+ageWeeks+ " week"+(ageWeeks==1?"":"s")+" ago");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
    var created='20120223';
    var year=Number(created.substr(0,4));
    var month = Number(created.substr(4,2));
    if (Number(created.substr(4,2)) < 10){
      month = '0'+ Number(created.substr(4,2));
    }
    var day=Number(created.substr(6,2));
    var dt = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    var dif = new Date().getTime() - Date.parse(dt);
    var divWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    alert(Math.round(dif/divWeek));
```